# How to make the Tab.Navigation Screens default background white in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have question what properties called to make the screens default white background in react native. Currently I used Tab.Navigator for the screen move.

**Here is my current screen.**

[image: Current Screen]

const Navigation = () => {

```
    return (

        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#200E32',
                inactiveTintColor: '#200E32',
                activeBackgroundColor: 'white',
                inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
                style: {
                    borderTopColor: '#FFC350',
                    borderTopWidth: 4
                }
            }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <Image style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} source={require('./assets/home.png')} />
                        ),
                    }}
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                />

                <Tab.Screen
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'My Cart',
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <Image style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} source={require('./assets/cart.png')} />
                        ),
                    }}
                    name="Cart"
                    component={MyCartScreen}
                />

                <Tab.Screen
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'Notification',
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <Image style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} source={require('./assets/notification.png')} />
                        ),
                    }}
                    name="Notification"
                    component={NotificationScreen}
                />

                <Tab.Screen
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'My Account',
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <Image style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} source={require('./assets/myaccount.png')} />
                        ),
                    }}
                    name="MyAccount"
                    component={MyAccountScreen}
                />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DefaultTheme from react-navigation library and set your background colour. So it will be set default for every screen without manually given to each screen.

**Try This:**

```
import { DefaultTheme, NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navTheme = DefaultTheme;
navTheme.colors.background = 'red';
```